# Cassandra read throw exceptions with C# driver

Tags: c#, performance, cassandra, cql, cql3

We want to measure Cassandra performance, so we plan to write 10800 rows data to one table, each row has about 1MB data. For the writing, it seems no problem.

When we tried to read all above 10800 rows from cassandra, it always throw exception like this:

```
Cassandra.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency One (0 replica(s) responded over 1 required)
   at Cassandra.TaskHelper.WaitToComplete[T](Task`1 task, Int32 timeout)
   at Cassandra.Session.Execute(IStatement statement)
   at Cassandra.Session.Execute(String cqlQuery, ConsistencyLevel consistency)
   at DataCloud.TestApps.CassandraTest.CassandraClient.Execute(String cqlQuery)
```

Then we modified the cassandra.yaml file manually to change the read timeout to enough time, it still the same exception.

What we used to query all the data is:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = ...; // The id is the partition key
```

So we change the rows count to 1024, still the reading throws exception, but this time it's different:

```
Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException: None of the hosts tried for query are available (tried: 127.0.0.1)
   at Cassandra.RequestHandler`1.GetNextConnection(IStatement statement, Boolean isLastChance)
   at Cassandra.RequestHandler`1.TrySend()
   at Cassandra.TaskHelper.WaitToComplete[T](Task`1 task, Int32 timeout)
   at Cassandra.Session.Execute(IStatement statement)
   at Cassandra.Session.Execute(String cqlQuery, ConsistencyLevel consistency)
   at DataCloud.TestApps.CassandraTest.CassandraClient.Execute(String cqlQuery)
```

We also tried 100 rows, it seems okay.

So, what's the best practice to read data in cassandra with C#? I think 10800MB data is not that huge, why it cannot read all of them? Or I missed something?

Thanks very much.

Comment: 1) Have you tried running the same queries from cqlsh? The first error is a Cassandra timeout (not a driver timeout) and that would point to the cluster being slow; 2) what version of the C# driver are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to investigate why you are getting read time outs from Cassandra (via [tracing](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/tracing-in-cassandra-1-2)), you shouldn't have to change the read time out settings in Cassandra (is your node under Windows?).

After that, at driver level, you can configure what to do when you get a read time out (implementing a [retry policy](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/src/Cassandra/Policies/IRetryPolicy.cs), sample [here](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/blob/master/src/Cassandra/Policies/DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.cs)) but generally is not necessary.

If you are reading cql rows that are about 1MB you could try by lowering the page size (default: 5000) using Statement.SetPageSize() method.